# Assign a hidden field value on default.aspx using BasePage Class methods

Tags: asp.net

Is that possible? The reason why am doing this is because I need to parse that variable into a an JQuery function so I wanted JQuery to read that field. Can I Assign that value in base class or I have to do it within default.aspx pageload method?

Comment: what do you mean by `BagePage Class methods`? You mean the **MasterPage**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you get the hidden field value using just Jquery ?

have a look at :

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/getting-value-of-hidden-input-field-loading-using-load